# How to set correctly React routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm building an app with React and I'm using React routes.

I have 3 main routes:

- If the user is logged in, show Dashboard
- If the user is not logged in, show SignIn page
- If the user clicks on ForgotPassword on the SignIn page, change url and show ForgotPassword page

*index.js*

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" component={App} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Suspense>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

*App.js*

```
{this.props.location.pathname === "/" && <Dashboard />}
<Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
<Route path="/users/:id" component={UserPage} />
{!authenticated && <Redirect to="/login" />}
```

When I try to open `"/"`, it redirects to `"/login"` but it doesn't render `Login` component.
When I replace `{!authenticated && <Redirect to="/login" />}` with `{!authenticated && <Login>}` it renders the component properly, but it doesn't change the url and it won't show the ForgotPassword page.

How do I set this properly?

Comment: Did you tried `<Route exact path="/" component={App} />` with `exact` in all routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reorder your switch:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Switch>
```

Then, maybe make that `App` something like

```
{!authenticated ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/users/:id" component={UserPage} />
    <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
    <Route path="/" component={Dashboard />
  </Switch>
)}
```

(though it could be simpler to just keep all routes in the top-level router/switch)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is order of the `Route` components and the use of `Switch` component.

When you redirect to `/login`, `Switch` will render the first matching route; for the `/login` route, `/` route also matches.

This is why `Login` component isn't rendered. `App` component is rendered for both `/` and `/login` routes.

#### Solution

Couple of solutions to this problem are described below:

**`exact` prop**

One way to solve the problem is to use the [exact](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool) prop. This will ensure that `/` route  doesn't matches `/login` BUT it will cause another problem: nested routes inside `App` component won't be rendered. This is because for nested route to be rendered, parent route also needs to be rendered.

**Re-order the `Route` components**

Another solution is to change the order of your routes as:

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
   <Route path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
   <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use render prop instead of component and the render prop give you the ability to do some checks and return the appropriate component

```
<Route render={(props) => !isAuth ? <Redirect to='/signin' /> : <Component {...props} /> } />
```